# script embedded in html testing url

Tags: javascript, html, cross-domain

I have an html file (example below) with a simple javascript function to check whether a URL exists.  However it works only for some existing URLs (not all), and it never works for non-existing ones -- just seems not to yield any result. I can't figure out what is wrong.

-- tsf

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<script>
function Exists(url)
{
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('HEAD',url,false);
    req.send();
    return req.status!=404;
}
</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<script>
if (Exists('http://stackoverflow.com/')) {
    document.write('Exists');
} else {
    document.write('Does not exist');
}
</script>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: Maybe : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: You can make a workaround with iframes or there are several ways to do it with jQuery (and the issue is as described by the fellow commenters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing the "[Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)" problem. This concept is to protect your web browsing experience so that pages you visit (i.e. bad JavaScript) cannot communicate with unknown servers and e.g. they don't violate your privacy (cannot steal your data).

The simplest solution to your problem: move the logic to your server (PHP, Ruby, Java, whatever...). Let your server perform HTTP requests and check for what you need. Then use `XMLHttpRequest()` to ask **your server** which is running the same domain and port, so nothing can go bad. That's all.

Comment: I guess that explains it.  I will follow your suggestion.